# Why is my program crashing and playing the sound repeatedly? (Python tkinter timer)

Tags: python, tkinter

I do not understand why, but when setTimer()'s first timer is done, the timerDone() sound plays on repeat and the program crashes, instead of continuing with the rest of the timers.
Can someone tell me why this is happening? Thanks in advance. Tell me if the question is not clear enough and I will do my best to explain. The functions in question are setTimer() and timerDone()

```
# IMPORTS #

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.font import *
from playsound import playsound
import os

# VARIABLES #

minutes = 0
notificationText = "There are no current reminders."
directory = os.getcwd()
isTimerDone = False
onBreak = False
pomodoros = 0


# FUNCTIONS #

def getFacialExpressions():
    return [False, False]


# TKINTER #

window = tk.Tk()

window.title("Focus-Ware")
bigFontRegular = Font(
    family="Helvetica",
    size=35,
)
bigFontItalic = Font(
    family="Helvetica",
    size=35,
    slant="italic"
)
regularFontItalic = Font(
    family="Helvetica",
    size=25,
    slant="italic"
)
window.geometry("500x500")
title = tk.Label(
    text="Focus-Ware",
    font=bigFontItalic,
    foreground="black",
)
timerTitle = tk.Label(
    text="Timer:",
    font=bigFontItalic,
    foreground="black"
)
timer = tk.Label(
    text="Not Started",
    font=bigFontRegular,
    foreground="black"
)

reminderTitle = tk.Label(
    text=notificationText,
    font=regularFontItalic,
    foreground="black"
)

reminder = tk.Label(
    text="Last Notification:",
    font=bigFontItalic,
    foreground="black"
)

def doNothing():
    return "nothing"

pomodoroDone = False





def timerDone():
    global onBreak
    global isTimerDone
    isTimerDone = True
    reminderTitle.config(text="The timer is done!")
    onBreak = not(onBreak)
    if onBreak:
        reminderTitle.config(text="Go on break!")
    else:
        reminderTitle.config(text="Get to work!")
    timer.config(text="Completed")
    playsound(f'{os.getcwd()}/Audio/notification.mp3')


def setTimer(mins=25):
    for i in range(4):
        timer.config(text="In Progress")
        window.after(1 * 60 * 1000, timerDone)
        timer.config(text="In Progress")
        window.after(1 * 60 * 1000, timerDone)
    window.after(30 * 60 * 1000, timerDone)


def resetTimer():
    timer.config(text="Not Started")


def reminder_f():
    reminderTitle.config(text="Remember to pay attention!")
    playsound(f'{os.getcwd()}/Audio/notification.mp3')


Start = tk.Button(
    command=setTimer,
    text="Start Pomodoro"
)

# DRIVER CODE #

# LOOP #
title.pack()
reminder.pack(pady=40)
reminderTitle.pack()
timerTitle.pack(pady=40)
timer.pack()
Start.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `setTimer()` will schedule eight calls to `timerDone()`, *that all happen at the same time* - one minute into the future.  (And a ninth call, 30 minutes into the future).  You would need to pass increasing delay values if you want the calls to be spread out in time.

Comment: But it needs to happen after 25, then 5, then 30 minutes. Is there a way to specifically do that?

Comment: @DanielPortas-Levy yes of course, just use some list, `from itertools import cycle` and then set the delay as `next(minutes)` where `minutes = cycle((25, 5, 30))`, then convert that to milliseconds too `.after(next(minutes) * 60 * 1000, ...)`

Comment: Would this work? I am not able to put it in the comment box for some reason.
https://pastebin.com/vS1PFRKb

Comment: Nevermind. I still have the same issue. It does not continue the function and runs timerDone() several times.

Comment: @jasonharper, is there a way to make sure the calls come one after another?

Comment: based on what you said, you need to schedule a these calls: `window.after(25 * 60 * 1000, timerDone)`; `window.after(30 * 60 * 1000, timerDone)`; `window.after(60 * 60 * 1000, timerDone)` and don't use any loops, just these three lines in the `setTimer` function